# Committing changes with your computer incorrectly set to a future date?

Tags: mercurial

I committed a change while my computer date was set to a month in the future, and pushed the change to Bitbucket. Someone else has since pulled and pushed their own change using their own computers proper date which is earlier than my change's future date.

I just started using Mercurial and don't have a good understanding of how it uses dates to track changes. Other than the date being displayed in the log summary not making sense, what, if any, are the other potential consequences of this kind of stupid move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no functional consequences.  In a DVCS like Mercurial or git a lot of commit metadata like date, author, and committer are entirely unvalidated at commit time.  They *are*, however, used to build up the hash that identifies the revision, so they can't be changed without changing that commit's hash.

There are be some tools, especially web views and thick clients, that will let you sort revisions by date, in which case the item would be mis-ordered, and some commands let you act on a date range which will now miss this commit, but everything important is based on commit parentage or sequence, not self-reported date.

Comment: Thanks. That helps address my immediate concerns. I guess I'll have to decide whether changing the history is worthwhile or not. Someone else has already committed after what would be the 'bad' changeset if I update the history.